# yii2 add option group label in dropdown list

Tags: php, yii2

This is my `dropdownlist` like..

```
<?= $form->field($queModel, 'qm_category_id')->dropdownList(QuestionCategory::getQuestionCat()) ?>
```

This is `getQuestionCat()` function

```
public static function getQuestionCat()
{
    $dataTmp = self::find()->all();
    $result = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($dataTmp, 'qc_id', 'qc_name', 'qcCourse.course_name');
    print_r($result); exit;
    return $result;
}
```

Above function return this array using ArrayHelper

[image]

show below image like..

[image]

In this dropdownlist the first `<optgroup label="">` set to `<optgroup label="Other">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map` function accepts closures, so you could use the following:

```
$result = \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($dataTmp, 'qc_id', 'qc_name', function($model) {
    if ($course_name = $model->qcCourse->course_name) {
        return $course_name;
    }
    else {
        return 'Other';
    }
});
```

Comment: @vishu then check your `$model` has relation `qcCource` or to make sure that it works - you could change the condition to debug, for example: `if (rand(0, 5) > 2) {}`